# Angular 2+ switching betweens elements, based on click

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So, I'm trying to use a angular way to send the buttons created to either the #start or #finish divs, based on click on the buttons selected, so in a way they would send themselves if you may if they follow a condition, which in this case is to be either inside of the #start or #finish divs. With Jquery, I just check what's the parent of certain element, if matches one, I send it to the other, and vice versa. Now with angular, I have been looking into the whole, rendering and stuff, but my head can't just understand the overall picture, and I even though I was able to click and send the element clicked to a different div, I couldn't do it with the other buttons created, and also with the button that was first clicked, in the other div.

```
<div class="ui raised very padded text container segment" 
  #finish>
    </div> 
<div class="ui raised very padded text container segment" #start>
    <button 
    *ngFor='let word of ge_array' 
    (click)="goToNext()" 
    >{{word}}</button>
  </div>
```

Does anybody know how to tackle this situation?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the buttons to appear under `start` until one of them is clicked and then they all appear under `finish`? And clicking them again sends them back to `start`?

Comment: Not all of them at once. Each one has their own actions, if one is clicked from Start, that button goes to Finish, and then if that same button gets clicked again, he goes back to Start. And that same logic works for all of the buttons that are coming from the *ngfor.

Comment: It seems like you should maintain two arrays: one with the `start` and one with `finish`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renan, I would change all your plan. I have an array of element. this elements have a property "place". I will show in two div one for "plan1" and the other for "plan2".

```
//the .ts is like
items:any[]=[{word:'uno',place:1},{word:'dos',place:1},{word:'tres',place:2}]

get items1(){
  return this.items.filter(it=>it.place==1);
}
get items2(){
  return this.items.filter(it=>it.place==2);
}

//the .hmtl like
<h2>place 1</h2>
  <button  *ngFor="let item of items1" (click)="item.place=2">{{item.word}}</button>
<h2>place 2</h2>
<button  *ngFor="let item of items2" (click)="item.place=1">{{item.word}}</button>
```

I would prefer using a getter and have "item1" and "item2". the click make that the property "place" of the item becomes 2 in place 1 and becomes 1 in place2

You can make two *ngFor over the same array also using a *ngIf like

```
<h1>place 1</h1>
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <button *ngIf="item.place==1" (click)="item.place=2">{{item.word}}</button>
</div>
<h1>place 2</h1>
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <button *ngIf="item.place==2" (click)="item.place=1">{{item.word}}</button>
</div>
```

and forget the getters

Comment: That's was a great solution and I'm appreciate your answer ;).